# Magento multilang - search results of all languages

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, search, language

Whenever i use the search function (not advanced search) i only get store specific answers.
So if a product is called `Civic Carbon Hood` in English and in Dutch `Civic Carbon Motorkap` I will get a problem when I search on the Dutch storeview for `Civic Carbon Hood`..

While it is the same product it won't find a hit. Now i found somewhere that it is related to the function `addStoreFilter`. So i tried to disable it everywhere i could find it relatable to the search or product function. Also commented the `setStore` function out just in case. Sadly enough this wasn't the solution.

My question is: where do i need to search or what do i need to modify etc.. Because going nuts over here searching for the resolution...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a very dirty answer. But atleast for when someone needs to know i changed it using the following code:
I first try the normal code (so searching within his own store).
`$collection = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getProductCollection();`
Then I check if there are results. If no I search in other stores using the following code:

```
$osi = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
// store old storeid to restore after getting the collection
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(1);
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->setStore(1);
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(1);
// Actually the first 2 are sufficient. Just to be sure also changed this one.
$collection2 = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getProductCollection();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($osi);
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->setStore($osi);
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId($osi);
```

As said.. Far from beautiful.. But it works and will continue to look for a neat solution.